# Else statement if .map does not ret

Tags: reactjs

I would like to check if jobPosts === {} meaning there are no jobPosts and if so set jobPostMarkup to a string stating "No Results Found" though I am struggling to work the functionality into the existing code?

```
render() {

const { jobPosts, loading,category, state } = this.props.data;

   let jobPostMarkup = !loading ? (

 jobPosts.map((jobPost) => 


 <JobPost key={jobPost.jobId} jobPost={jobPost} />)

) : ( 
<Skeleton/>

   )
```

Comment: if `jobPosts === {}`, which in an object then you can't use `Array.map()`on it.

Answer (score 0):

You can count the amount of keys that an object contains to see if the object is empty. When the object has 0 keys this means it is empty.

The full code should be

```
render() {

const { jobPosts, loading,category, state } = this.props.data;

   let jobPostMarkup = !loading ? (

   if(Object.keys(jobPosts).length === 0) jobPostMarkup = "No Results Found";


 <JobPost key={jobPost.jobId} jobPost={jobPost} />)

) : (
```

```js
let jobPosts = {}

let jobPostMarkup = "";

if(Object.keys(jobPosts).length === 0) jobPostMarkup = "No Results Found";

console.log(jobPostMarkup)
```

Comment: Thanks. Stephen though this gives me a  Unexpected token on the line  if(Object.keys(jobPosts).length === 0) jobPostMarkup = "No Results Found";

Comment: @benpalmer I have added a snippet of a working example. I do not get the same error. What is the exact error?

Comment: just said syntax error -  though i added this line under neath and its working, thanks for your help   if(Object.keys(jobPosts).length === 0) jobPostMarkup = "No Results Found";

Answer (score 0):

```
render() {

const { jobPosts, loading,category, state } = this.props.data;

   let jobPostMarkup = !loading ? (

 jobPosts.map((jobPost) => 


 <JobPost key={jobPost.jobId} jobPost={jobPost} />)

) : ( 
<p> 
   )


if(Object.keys(jobPosts).length === 0) jobPostMarkup = "No Results Found";
```

Just needed to add the bottom line.